# Colorization of mathematics

Tags: soft-question, education

I am currently in the process of starting to formalize my mathematics notes, both hand-written and digital. In that I have reached somewhat of a conundrum. I have learned both through practice and formal education that colorization can help the students visualize and learn the material better.

My question is about if and if so how colorization should be used.

The website *Better explained* has a [longer article](https://betterexplained.com/articles/colorized-math-equations/) discussing the benefits of colorization. Here is one example

[image]

In my opinion this explanation is somewhat cluttered, there are too many colors in addition the purple and magenta are to similar. I have a couple of suggestions to improve this

- Highlight one color at a time (this could easily be done in a beamer presentation), however I am afraid this would consume too much time.
- Have one color for variables, one for constants the rest remains black.
- Everything black.

Are any of the suggestions above good, or are there better solutions I have not considered? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I agree that this example is bad, In general, I don't like colors at all. If you must, then every once in a while you can highlight one particular part of an expression to call attention to it. Note that some readers are color blind and won't be able to tell red from green, maybe neither from black.

Comment: Make all black and drop the confusing part that starts with "To"

Comment: I think colours *can* be used in a helpful way, but in the example you showed it definitely confuses more than it helps.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Seems a bit like your suggesting "don't ever say or write anything". In this way btw. you never will make mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This is rather a *soft question* - it's primarily opinion-based  and not entirely on topic.

Personally, colours don't help my learning, understanding or retention of a specific concept. The psychedelica of the equation is rather confusing, and when you start trying to work with even more complex equations, the result is far too complicated. What's more, with all these wild colours trying to grab our attention to the important details, the question is: *which bits are actually the really key ones?* If you picked the key detail, the bit people will forget and highlight that, sure, or highlight an equation *in one colour*, that is a perfectly valid strategy I have seen many fellow students use, but the way you are doing it is, in my opinion, ineffectual and counterproductive.